# why does window.setInterval thing stops working after about 62 seconds

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, setinterval

For some reason the window.setInterval thing stops working after about 60 seconds if its window is not visible enough.

Does anybody know how I can make it continue until I **tell** it to stop?

Here is a simple demo. I run it in chrome a web site, it does not stop in the VS debug environment.

```
function pseudoBot2() {
  const startTime = new Date();
  startTimeMs = startTime.getTime();
  const funcId = setInterval(logIt, 1000);
}
function logIt(){
  const now = new Date();
  const elapsed = now.getTime() - startTimeMs;
  console.log("TX at " + Math.round(elapsed / 1000));
}
```

If you start it with the chrome debugger console on then minimise its window then maximise after about 2 minutes the console log contains something like

```
.
.
TX at 61
TX at 62
TX at 63
TX at 105
TX at 165
.
.
```

Comment: Browsers are aggressive about conserving resources in background tabs. The interval shouldn't *stop* though but get throttled. Maybe paused and resumed. Are you sure nothing like this happens?

Comment: @VLAZ It gets a bit throttled as you see by the log at 105 seconds. But then it stops completely.

Comment: Is there some way to turn off the throttling?

Comment: Does the interval resume when the browser tab is re-focused, or just die completely?

Comment: It's probably a bad idea, but `setInterval` in a worker doesn't get throttled. So you [can do something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51391172/14357)

Comment: Why turn of the throttling? That sounds like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Note that it's easier (and faster) to just use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date().getTime()`.

Comment: Clearly the moderator has never used wikipedia. It's not plagiarism if you attach the reference.